# How to check for NSDecimalNumber.zero() in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdecimalnumber

Using 'num1' as a comparison reference to determine if 'num2' or 'num3' are zero.  Have done this successfully in Objective-C, and am trying to do it in Swift:

```
let num1: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber.zero()
let num2: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString("0")
let num3: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString("0.000001")

if num1.compare(num2) == NSOrderedSame {
    println("They match")
}
```

This attempt results in: "error: use of unresolved identifier 'NSOrderedSame'."
What is the proper way to accomplish this in Swift?  (Have searched the book and web, but missing something possibly obvious, thank you).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you mean: `num1.compare(num2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame`

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Now to learn how to find that myself in the apple documentation  : )

Comment: Swift can infer the `NSComparisonResult` so you can drop it (still need the `.`)

Answer (score 7):

in *Swift* that can happen an easier way, like e.g. this:

```
    if num1 == num2 {
        println("They match")
    }
```

## BACKGROUND

(extracted from [Using Swift Cocoa and Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html), *Object Comparison* section)

> *Swift* and *Objective-C* objects are typically compared in *Swift* using the `==` and `===` operators. *Swift* provides a default implementation of the `==` operator for objects that derive from the `NSObject` class. In the implementation of this operator, *Swift* invokes the `isEqual:` method defined on the `NSObject` class.

Comment: Are you sure this is true about `NSNumber` objects?

Comment: I could not find the reference currently (I will) but the _Swift_ automatically converts those `==` opreators to an `-isEqual:` method for Obj-C objects, like e.g. `NSNumbers`.

Comment: I'm trying to find it again... to be fair, in the last two weeks I've been reading all possible documentation of _Swift_ and I have no idea where I found it... but I will find it again, because that would be a very useful information.

Comment: According to my test, it appears to work, will look for the reference also.  (I haven't tested for the cases of NSOrderAscending and NSOrderDescending though).

Comment: @LeoNatan, I found the reference again, and I've added to my answer.

Comment: @H_H, I've attached the reference. :)

Comment: @LeoNatan,  Thank you!  I should try the <, >, <=, and >= comparisons too, they might work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with `NSDecimalNumber` often, I'll plug my own operator overloads here: https://gist.github.com/anisoptera/5708afc32454ed868363

Takes care of that irritating unclear "NSOrdered..." comparison and even lets you do such crazy things as add two `NSDecimalNumber`s with the + operator!